# Java or Spring async TaskExeuctor that supports transaction association?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to work with an `@TransactionalEventListener` (Spring 4.3) that will run an event after a transaction completes.

However, I've got my own `ApplicationEventMulticaster` that I'm building and using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for.

The docs for `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` state:

```
    /**
     * Set a custom executor (typically a {@link org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor})
     * to invoke each listener with.
     * <p>Default is equivalent to {@link org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor},
     * executing all listeners synchronously in the calling thread.
     * <p>Consider specifying an asynchronous task executor here to not block the
     * caller until all listeners have been executed. However, note that asynchronous
     * execution will not participate in the caller's thread context (class loader,
     * transaction association) unless the TaskExecutor explicitly supports this.
     * @see org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor
     * @see org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor
     */
    public void setTaskExecutor(Executor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }
```

However, I am unable to locate an Async `TaskExecutor` that is transaction aware. Does something like this exist in the Java ecosystem already?

Currently, my events never get ran because the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is not transaction aware, so it always thinks there is no current transaction - ignoring the Event Listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently on stable `TaskExecutor` which will work with spring managed transactions as currently, Spring binds transactions to the Threads via ThreadLocals.

But you can easily have asynchronous `@TransactionalEventListener` in your code by just adding `@Async` annotation on your `@TransactionalEventListener` listener methods. Just remember that the Spring will publish the event to the listener only when the publisher was called in the boundaries of the transaction and its after commit phase, but the transaction finishes so the object is in the detached state.

So say if you need to publish event from within a Transaction

```
@Service
public class Service {

        @Autowired
        private SomeRepository someRepository;

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

        @Transactional
        public void create(SomeEntity entity) {
            someRepository.save(entity);
            SomeEntityCreatedEvent event = new SomeEntityCreatedEvent();
            event.entity = entity;
            applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
        }

        public static final class SomeEntityCreatedEvent {
            private SomeEntity entity;

            public SomeEntity getSomeEntity() {
               return entity;
            }
        }
}
```

The listener will get the event with already detached entity, so changes on it won't be propagated to the datastore.

```
@Component
public class UpdatesListener {

    @Async // here you can controll the task executor which needs to take care of this thread
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    public void handleCustom(Service.SomeEntityCreatedEvent event) {
        // here entity is deatached
        SomeEntity entity = event.getSomeEntity();
        System.out.println("Created some entity with id" + entity.getId());
    }

}
```

Ahh, and do not overwrite the default `SyncTaskExecutor` on the `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` instead use `@Async` on listeners.

Comment: What's the reason for the `SyncTaskExecutor` note?

Comment: @JJZabkar That's an executor that runs the tasks in the same thread, that is just executing the `run()` method directly. So as it runs in the same thread it is aware of the Transaction so it can listen to after commit stage ....

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It makes sense that it would have to happen that way so that the transaction synchronization can work, it seems I originally had it backwards.